# Perception of professionalism on idiom usage at work

Tags: communication, united-states

I work in the United States at a company that can be described as fairly informal. I work in the IT Security profession, leading / mentoring leading a team. Often I use idioms when talking to team members. Examples are listed below:

1. with a grain of salt - doubtful , skeptical
2. par for the course - as expected or the normal result
3. nitty gritty - fine details

**Could using idioms such as these when talking within the team be perceived as unprofessional?**

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: What's prompted the question? Has it been mentioned to you that you shouldn't be using these terms? Maybe there is a bigger picture we are missing, as it seems an odd question to ask currently

Answer (score 11):

Stop over-analysing. You are merely speaking idiomatic English -- defined as the way the language is normally spoken.

Comment: And at least two out of the three idioms are even used by myself, not a native english speaker, so they should be fine with anyone using workplace english.

Answer (score 1):

> Could using idioms such as these when talking within the team be
>   perceived as unprofessional?

It depends on the team.

In an informal US-based team, probably not. But if the team includes lots of folks whose native language is not US English, then it might be confusing. And continued use of idioms when you know they are confusing to team members could indeed be considered unprofessional.

The real point in communicating is *understanding*. Does everyone understand correctly when you use these idioms? If so, then you are fine. If not, reconsider your usage.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say no, the usage of phrases similar to your examples in a professional setting is not unprofessional, and should not be perceived as such.

The examples you've given are particularly common in English, and used in everyday conversation. As long as you stay away from phrases that might be considered to be slang, or especially informal, you've got nothing to worry about.

You yourself say that your company could be described as fairly informal, so that should put your mind at ease.

Answer (score 0):

Plain speaking is often the preferred way of communicating.  The idioms you've used here are commonly known, so won't be an issue.

However, avoid over-use.  When you see your team-mates start rolling their eyes at yet another idiom, you know you've gone too far.